# How to implement a C++ vector in Android?

Tags: android, c++, vector, structure

I'm working in Android with opencv library. I found some code in c++ for image processing which contains the following line:

```
    vector<pair<CvPoint, pair<double, double> > > hlines;
```

How can I create a structure like this in android in order to save a point and two doubles?

Comment: You could always write your own class (java), and have an ArrayList of objects of that class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java doesn't have pairs; Java programmers tend to write their own class for that kind of thing. e.g.,

```
class HLine {
    public final CvPoint point;
    public final double x;
    public final double y;

    public HLine(CvPoint point, double x, double y) {
        this.point = point;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Then you can just create an `ArrayList<HLine>`.

Comment: Thanks Chris Jester, this was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look at Arraylist...... it is also a array but you don't have to define the size of it...
syntax :

```
ArrayList<datatype> variable_name=new ArrayList<datatype>();
```